# Password Validate With Regex

Tags: regex, validation

Below is the regex which validates my passwords:

```
(((?=.*\\d{2,20})(?=.*[a-z]{2,20})(?=.*[A-Z]{3,20})(?=.*[@#$%!@@%&*?_~,-]{2,20})).{9,20}[^<>'\"])
```

Basically what I want is that it contains all above given characters in password. But it needs those characters in sequence e.g
it validates `23aaAAA@!`, but it does not validate`a2@!AAAa`.

Comment: I also have the Same problem.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Is there a reason you need to use a regex for this, instead of validating the password another way?

Comment: password is generated based on this regex.so we need to validate it based on that regex.

Comment: Would validating it against multiple regexes be an option? e.g. `password.matches("[A-Z]") && password.matches("[a-z]") && password.matches("\d") && password.matches("[^A-Za-z\d]")`?

Comment: @BasharatAli:  you doesn't give any feedback, have you tried to simply insert the regex inline as this? ``(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2,20})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,20})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3,20})(?=(?:.*[@#$%!&*?_~,-]){2,20}).{9,20}[^<>'\"]``.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add nested capturing groups to keep the chars validation not strictly as a sequence. The regex can be also simplified as follow (without extra groups):

```
(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2,20})
(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,20})
(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3,20})
(?=(?:.*[@#$%!&*?_~,-]){2,20})
.{9,20}
[^<>'\"] # This matches also the newline char, i don't think you really want this...
```

In java use it as follows to match the :

```
String regex = "(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2,20})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,20})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3,20})(?=(?:.*[@#$%!&*?_~,-]){2,20}).{9,20}[^<>'\"]";
String password = "23aaA@AA!@X"; // This have to be 10 chars long at least, no newline

if (password.matches(regex))
    System.out.println("Success");
else
    System.out.println("Failure");
```

The regex requires a password with (all not strictly in sequence):

- `(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2,20})`: 2 numbers
- `(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,20})`: 3 lowercase lettes
- `(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3,20})`: 3 uppercase letters
- `(?=(?:.*[@#$%!&*?_~,-]){2,20})`: 2 of the symbols in the chars group
- `.{9,20}`: Min length of 9 and max of 20
- `[^<>'\"]`: One char that is not in (`<`,`>`,`'`,`"`) (NOTE: this matches also the newline)

So the `min`/`max` is actually `10`/`21` but the last statemente matches also the newline, so in the online regex demo, the visible chars will be between `9` and `20`.

Regex online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yS5dG2/2)

Comment: Php is PCRE based so it will work as expected, i can't be sure for Asp.net (it works in C#). The spacing is allowed by the free spacing ``(?x)`` modifier (not available in java), but place the groups inline to fix

Comment: let me try if does not work than i will get back to stack

Comment: @BasharatAli: sorry for some reason i think you have to accomplish this in java, i really need to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to build a single regexp, because nobody will ever be able to read nor change this expression ever again. It's to hard to understand.

"a2@!AAAa" will never validate because it needs 2 digits.

If you want a password, that contains a minmuum and maximum number of chars from a group. simply count them.

```
public class Constraint {

    private Pattern pattern;
    public String regexp = "";
    public int mincount=2;
    public int maxcount=6;

    public Constraint(String regexp, int mincount, int maxcount) {
        this.mincount=mincount;
        this.maxcount=maxcount;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    }

    public boolean fit(String str)
    {
        int count = str.length() - pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll("").length();
        return count >= mincount && count <= maxcount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pattern.toString();
    }
}


public class Test {

    static Constraint[] constraints = new Constraint[] {
            new Constraint("[a-z]",2,20),
            new Constraint("[A-Z]",2,20),
            new Constraint("\\d",2,20),
            new Constraint("["+Pattern.quote("@#$%!@@%&*?_~,-")+"]",2,20),
            new Constraint("[<>'\\\"]",0,0)
    };

    public static boolean checkit(String pwd)
    {
        boolean ok=true;
        for (Constraint constraint:constraints)
        {
            if (constraint.fit(pwd)==false)
            {
                System.out.println("match failed for constraint "+constraint);
                ok=false;
            }
        }
        return ok;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkit("23aaAAA@!");
        checkit("a2@!AAAa");
    }
}
```